# Magento2: setFilterGroups(array) SearchCriteria Error

Tags: magento2, error, search-criteria

I have the following code:

```
$filter1 = $this->_filterBuilder->setField('name')
    ->setValue('%'.$searchTerm.'%')
    ->setConditionType("like")
    ->create();
$filter2 = $this->_filterBuilder->setField('description')
    ->setValue('%'.$searchTerm.'%')
    ->setConditionType("like")
    ->create();
$filterOR = $this->_filterGroupBuilder->addFilter($filter1)->addFilter($filter2)->create();
$this->_searchCriteriaBuilder->setFilterGroups([$filterOR]);
$this->_searchCriteriaBuilder->addSortOrder($searchOrder, SortOrder::SORT_ASC);
$searchCriteria = $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder->setCurrentPage($page)->setPageSize($pageSize)->create();
$searchResults = $this->_productRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
```

It throws an error:

> Call to undefined method
>   Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder::setFilterGroups()

why?

Comment: simple....there is no method `setFilterGroups` in the class `Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method setFilterGroups in the class `Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder`
Not sure if this will work but you can try to remove the line that contains `setFilterGroups`  and after the line

```
$searchCriteria = $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder->setCurrentPage($page)->setPageSize($pageSize)->create();
```

add this

```
$searchCriteria->setFilterGroups([$filterOR]);
```

there is a mehtod `setFilterGroups` in `Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaInterface` and `SearchCriteria` class.

Comment: how can i reset the builder to create a new after?

Comment: sorry, I don't know.